# Button in relative layout not affected by setting layout margins

Tags: android, user-interface, button, dialog

A custom `Dialog` box with a `RelativeLayout` contains a `Button` widget that won't change its margins, regardless of direction. Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#99000000">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dialogtitle" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Some text" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dialogtext" android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@id/dialogtitle"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/dialogbuttoninfo" android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Doesn't care about margins"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginLeft="128dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Padding works but only moves the text inside the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do?I can add a right margin & it works

Comment: Its for a Dialog, so maybe that explains the variability

Comment: also, what the hell is the `mumps` tag?

Comment: wiki mumps language. its somewhat amusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems crappy but have you tried putting it all in a `LinearLayout` instead? or perhaps removing `android:orientation="horizontal"`. I dont think `RelativeLayout` cares about orientation from what I've seen. Also I think, but might be wrong, that if you do a `LinearLayout` then you won't need to have `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` in there either.

After cleaning it up a bit (sorry but its so hard to read when its compressed as it was in the question) you also didn't state where the last `TextView` , `dialogbuttoninfo` was supposed to be relative to everything else, I think you have to do that for `Relative layouts` to behave properly, I've had some squirrely things happen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#99000000">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogtext"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialogbuttoninfo"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Doesn't care about margins"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="128dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice name. Sarcasm noted. I'm in grad school too. Yeah the Llayout works, maybe I'll use it. The Android UI tools drive me nuts. No matter what I do, I'm sure it will all unravel once I start testing on different devices. Thanks guy.

Comment: haha quite a name yourself. i have had quite a number of frustrations with inconsistencies with layout as well, fortunately with android and java there always seems to be another way to get anything done.

Comment: IMO the best way is to use opengl in a glsurfaceview. its basically a blank canvas with no restrictions and almost no 'android'.

Comment: hrm thats interesting. ill have to check that out, everyday on here i find totally new ways to get things done.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to align the left of the button against something before the margin has real meaning.